# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule to ignore portion of URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, addition, rules

I have the following URL:

`http://test.com/foo/some-random-string/bar/?id=xxx`

I would like wordpress to ignore the portion /some-random-string/ and effectively call this URL:

`http://test.com/foo/bar/?id=xxx`

I've tried many things but I haven't a clue as to whether I'm any closer or not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me in case you're interested:

`add_rewrite_rule('^foo/([^/]*)/bar/?', 'index.php?pagename=foo/bar', 'top');`

FYI the /some-random-string/ is injected for SEO purposes but I needed wordpress to ignore it. The ?id=xxx is used to query an external API.